# How does the ellipsis $x^2+2y^2=2$ gets represented to $x=\sqrt{2}\cos\theta; y= \sin(\theta)$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Just like the title says,
How does the ellipsis with equation
$$x^2+2y^2=2$$
becomes represented as
$$x=\sqrt{2}\cos\theta; y= \sin(\theta)$$
in polar coordinates?

can someone help me to understand the translation between cartesian to polar here?

This is for evaluating a double integral, btw. But I can't understand on my own how to get that transformation.

Comment: Start from the basics:  if a point is given in Cartesian coordinates, how do you rewrite it in polar coordinates?

Comment: well, the farthest I can go is $r^2\cos^2{\theta} + 2r^2\sin^2{\theta} = 2 $ From here I don't know where to go...

Comment: This is *not* polar coordinates but a parametrization.

Comment: @msmilkshake you neglected the factor 2 in front of the cosine.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, :facepalm: you're right... I am mixing stuff...

Comment: Do you happen to know what [tag:elliptic-integrals] are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the transformation here is based on polar coordinates but actually is called a parametrisation (as stated in the comments). Precisely, you wish to find values of $x$ and $y$ such that the above equation is true. In your case, plugging in $x=\sqrt{2}\cos\theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$ yields $$(\sqrt{2}\cos\theta)^2+2\sin^2\theta=2\cos^2\theta+2\sin^2\theta=2,$$ since $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$. Then, instead of evaluating a double integral over $x$ and $y$, you just use your transformation and evaluate it over $r$ and $\theta$, of course without forgetting the Jacobian.

Comment: Gotta think for this a little bit. How would I go from the starting cartesian equation into the final polar equation?

Comment: What I don't know what to do is just start with the cartesian equation and end with x and y in terms of $r$ and $\theta$

Comment: @msmilkshake Suppose you didn't have the factor 2 in front of the $y$. Then you would just have the equation of a disk of radius $\sqrt{2}$, every point of which can be accessed with a little trigonometry, hence the polar coordinates.

Comment: What I'm essentially saying is that if you recognise some kind of equation of a disk for instance, then polar coordinates should be used (since it will greatly simplify your integral evaluation). And here, the polar coordinates will be transformed a little bit since you have a factor 2 in front of the $y$ coordinate that you should consider in order for the equation to be correct. Hope this helps.